# Иконка на Visual Studio 2022 C++ Windows Forms

Tags: c++, winforms, clr, visual-studio-2022

Помогите пожалуйста поменять иконку в своей программе на Visual Studio 2022. Пишу на C++ CLR Windows Forms. Добавляю икону в свойства формы через конструктор, но иконка добавляется только в саму форму, но сам значок файла exe не меняется.
Добавил путь к значку в коде MyForm.h. Не помогает. Менял расположение файла с рабочего стола в директорию проекта. Не помогает.

Comment: Значек исполняемого файла задается в ресурсах приложения, а не програмно.

Comment: И как мне это сделать ? Пробовал по разному. Значек не меняется

Comment: Ладно, нашел как все сделать быстро. Правый клик на проекте -добавить ресурс -импорт - файл ico. Пересобирать проект. Всё